# Setting Content Type in node.js express Post Query Not Working

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, express

I have a POST request using the express framework that I am using to submit a query to a rest api.  The relevant snippet is:

```
var request = require('request');

app.post('/compute', function(req, postResponse) {
  var queryJSON = req.param('query');

  postResponse.header("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");
  postResponse.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request({
      "url":'somerealurl',
      "method": "POST",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "rejectUnauthorized": false,
      "form": queryJSON
    },

    function (error, response, body) {
      // Do some real stuff here
    }
  );
});
```

Overall, this is working and I am able to submit queries.  However, while I am trying to set the content type of the request to be "application/json", this does not seem to be working correctly.  When I look at the query in the chrome console, I see that the content type has not been set and remains the default, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

[image: Image of request in console with wrong content type]

Any help with how to set the content type correctly would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the request definintion to the following sovled this:

```
request({
  "url":'somerealurl',
  "method": "POST",
  "json": queryJSON
},
```